# C++ select()/threads or an alternative to handle multiple clients in a server

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, select, posix

I am trying **to learn C++ (with prior programming knowledge)** by creating a **server application with multiple clients**. Server application will run on Raspberry Pi/**Debian** (Raspbian). I thought this would also be a good opportunity to learn about **low-level concurrent programming with threads (e.g. POSIX)**. Then I came across with `select()` function which basically allows usage of blocking functions in a single thread to handle multiple clients, which is interesting. Some people here on StackOverflow mentioned that **threads cause a lot of overhead and `select()` seems to be a nice alternative.**

In reality, I will have 1-3 clients connected but I would like to keep my application flexible. As a structure design, I was thinking about a **main thread** invoking **a data thread (processing stuff non-stop)** and a **server thread (listening for incoming connections)**. Since `accept()` call is blocking, the latter one needs to be a separate thread. If a client connects, then **for each client, I may need a separate thread as well**.

At the end, worker thread will write to the shared memory and *client threads* will read from there and communicate with the clients. Some people were opposing to the usage of threads but in my understanding, **threads are good** if they are **invoked rarely** (and long living) and if there are **blocking function calls**. For the last one as it seems there is the `select()` function, which used in a loop, allows for handling of multiple sockets in a single thread.

I think at least for the data processing and server `accept()` call, I will need 2 separate threads initiated at the beginning. I may handle all clients with `select()` in a single thread or separate threads. What would be the correct approach and are there smarter alternatives?

Comment: You could do the entire thing in a single thread if you wanted, or you could do a thread per function... it's a design decision based on the specifics of what you need.  A note on `accept`... if you set the socket to non-blocking, you can `select` on a listening socket to know if you can `accept`.  I'd also add that I wouldn't say threads cause a *lot* of overhead... sure there's some, but there can clearly be benefits for lots of data processing.  And that's the bottom line in my opinion: threads can be used to simplify blocking APIs, but they really shine when you have heavy processing.